# Munkres' "Topology" - Exercise 7(d) Section 9

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, set-theory, recursion

This is the exercise:

> (c) Construct a sequence $\{A_n\}_{n \in \Bbb Z_+}$ of infinite sets such that $\forall n \in \Bbb Z_+, A_{n+1} \text{ has cardinality greater than } A_{n}$.

This is the definition of "cardinality greater than":

> Let $A.B \neq \emptyset$. We say that $A$ has *cardinality greater than* $B$ if and only if there exists an injection mapping $B$ into $A$ and there is no injection mapping $A$ into $B$.

**My attempt**

The natural choice is letting $A_1 = \Bbb Z_+$ and $A_{n+1} = \mathcal{P}(A_n)$, where $\mathcal{P}$ denotes the power-set.
Now, my problem is that in order to do so we must define a function $h$, by the Principle of Recursive Definition, such that:

$$ \begin{align} h(1) &= A_1 \\ h(n+1) &= \mathcal{P}(A_n) \end{align}$$

however I am missing the codomain of such function (without which the definition is not well-posed) and I do not know how to construct it from the Principles of Naive Set Theory.

As always, any hint or comment is welcome and let me know if I can explain myself clearer!

Comment: One question why do you need to find such a function, is the definition of greater cardinality that you provide not enough? Let us just do one step then $h : A_{n+1} \to A_n$ where $A_{n+1} = \mathcal{P}(A_n)$ this is certainly no injection since the power set contians all subsets of $A_1$ (Probably one needs to exclude $A_1 \neq \emptyset$), hence by above one would be done.

Comment: By induction, from the axioms of ZFC, at each step you have a set, so the union of all of those is a set $X$. Those are just elements of $\mathcal{P}(X)$

Comment: @Daàvid thank you very much for your answer! However, does that mean that there also exists a set which contains all of $A_n$‘s? Because I can not see it directly by induction.

Comment: @a.s.graduatestudent Thanks for the answer! I need the function to define $A_n$ rigorously as the value of such a function (otherwise we would be constructing sets without making sure that such a construction exists and is unique). I didn’t understand the solution you proposed.

Comment: The collection of all the $A_n$ exists by Replacement.

Comment: I deleted the tag "general-topology" because your question does not concern topology.